# How to disallow selection of text on website?

Tags: javascript, content

I have a question about preventing the selection of content and right-clicking with your mouse on a website. Some websites that I have encountered display a dialog which prohibits right-clicking but the website in question does not show any dialog. To visually make it clear, here is the website in question: http://www.amandakjones.com/homemade-creamy-garlic-dressing.php.

Notice that you are not allowed to right-click, let alone select text. I would like to know how this is done.

Comment: Copyright laws is what protects your content. JavaScript and other tricks will never achieve that no matter how hard your try.

Comment: Why do you need it? If anyone wants to copy it they will find a way, even if it means retyping the whole thing. (or use F12 in the browser to copy it from HTML)

Comment: It appears you've added the JavaScript code on the web page. I would like to advise you to remove it, because now I can't even right-click on an hyperlink. Moreover, just running `document.body.onselectstart = document.oncontextmenu = null` removes the contraints completely.

Comment: I hate this "feature". As I read a website, I am constantly selecting text as a sort of super short-term bookmark. When I come across websites like this, I make a note in my mind to avoid them... and there is more than 1 website which I commonly see in google and avoid only because of this.

Comment: If the goal is to annoy your users, might as well take a screenshot of the website and then replace the text with the image.

Comment: Also key combinations such as ctrl+a ctrl+c still work, and I don't think their is anyway of stopping this. And it's annoying.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> How to disallow selection of text on website?

You don't.
It's effectively impossible, assuming some minimal effort on the part of the person who wants the text. All you can really do is create speed bumps that will do nothing but irritate them. Also note that there are perfectly valid uses for the right-click menu (for example) that have nothing to do with stealing your content. If the person is after one of those, then you're *really* going to be annoying them.

Pretty much all attempts at this (preventing right-click or text selection) depend upon JavaScript, which means:

1. I can temporarily disable JavaScript.
2. I can use a browser that doesn't run JavaScript at all.
3. I can view source via the browser chrome menus.
4. I can view source via a key combination.
5. I can select large chunks of text by double-clicking on paragraphs.
6. I can select all via key combination and edit externally.
7. I can fetch the document with wget or similar.
8. I can feed the page to a mobilizer (Instapaper, Readability, etc.) then copy the text unrestricted from there.
9. I can save to Evernote or similar.
10. Besides the numerous workarounds, these tricks tend to be fragile. Some Firefox extension I have–there's nothing installed that *targets* this sort of thing–is allowing me to right click on that site without issue. The same may be the case for modifications to other browsers.

The list goes on.
If you don't want people copying your text, then don't put it someplace they can get to it.

If, for some reason, all you actually need to do is take some control of the *appearance* of text being selected, that can be accomplished with the [`user-select` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select) (or [::selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::selection) though it seems like it's on the way out), but that has no effect on the *ability* to copy the affected text.

Comment: There's even a built-in Firefox option - Options > Content > Enable Javascript > Advanced > Disable or replace context menus

Comment: Here's another one:  At one point, I'd run across one that pops up an alert when you right-clicked, and accidentally discovered that if you held down the left mouse button while you did the right-click, the alert never showed and the context menu worked just fine.  IIRC, this was bare-bones Firefox install, no extension at all

Comment: "If you don't want people copying your text, then don't put it someplace they can get to it". Nailed it perfectly.

Comment: Moreover, 99% of the time, you're really annoying legitimate visitors who would actually promote your site/product or otherwise increase your revenue. When I visit a site and then find that I can't use context search to look up a word, google a phrase, or IMDb a movie title, I immediately stop visiting the site. I imagine there are a lot of other people out there that are equally offended by this practice with zero intention of "stealing content".

Answer (score 5):

I think, it's a really bad practice and annoying but the site itself using the script below.

```
<script>
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false");
    function disableSelection(target){
        if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //For IE 
            target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
        else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //For Firefox
            target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
        else //All other route (For Opera)
            target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
        target.style.cursor = "default"
    }
    disableSelection(document.body);
</script>
```

Comment: I removed the incomplete/invalid code at the start (due to copy/paste). This was unnecessary anyway since it targeted out-of-date browsers.